# ¿Por qué fue usado el subjuntivo (y especificamente el subjuntuvo imperfecto) en una noticia sobre Francisco Sagasti?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

¿Por qué fue usado el subjuntivo (y especificamente el subjuntivo imperfecto) para los verbos "destituir" y "renunciar" en una noticia sobre Francisco Sagasti? Se usaría la misma forma también en el habla coloquial o solo se usa de esta manera en el contexto más formal?

[image]

> Francisco Sagasti se ha convertido en el tercer presidente de Perú en una semana, después de que los diputados destituyeran el pasado 9 de noviembre al ya exmandatario Martín Vizcarra y su sustituto, Manuel Merino, renunciara este día 15 ante las presiones de marchas masivas contra todo lo que rodeó su nombramiento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La locución "después de que", cuando expresa posterioridad, puede usar indicativo o subjuntivo, como se explica en el 25.14h de la [Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi):

> Cuando *después* expresa posterioridad, rechaza el futuro [...]. En estos contextos temporales, alternan indicativo y subjuntivo el español americano. El uso del subjuntivo es compartido por el español europeo, en el que constituye la opción mayoritaria.

Es decir, en el **español europeo**, se usa mayoritariamente el **subjuntivo**. En el **español americano**, se utilizan **ambos (indicativo o subjuntivo)**. En el ejemplo de la pregunta, al referirse a un evento en el pasado, las opciones serían: indicativo (pretérito perfecto simple):

- Francisco Sagasti se ha convertido en el tercer presidente de Perú en una semana, después de que los diputados **destituyeron** el pasado 9 de noviembre a Martín Vizcarra.

o subjuntivo (pretérito imperfecto):

- Francisco Sagasti se ha convertido en el tercer presidente de Perú en una semana, después de que los diputados **destituyeran** el pasado 9 de noviembre a Martín Vizcarra.

Al no existir un pretérito perfecto simple en subjuntivo, el pretérito perfecto simple de indicativo se transforma en el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo.

Comment: El hecho de que «después de que habían destituido» funciona perfectamente bien podría también explicar por qué llegó a usarse el subjuntivo en este contexto (ya que en las formas de -ra puede ser el pluscuamperfecto del indicativo).